# What is the latest version of TurboC?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ide, turbo-c

In my college they have prescribed Turbo C, for my academics. I know it is pretty old, but I want to download the latest version of it. I have a turbo c of 1980, a DOS version.

Is any latest version available for it?

Is Borland C++ is different from Turbo C++?

Comment: "In my college they have prescribed Turbo C, for my academics" - you should transfer to a new school.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C), the last version of Turbo C was 2.0 in 1989, though there was a Turbo C++ which last came out in version 3 in 1992. It's available as freeware, which is why it's popular in some schools in some BRIC countries (especially India it seems).

Comment: @Mysticial In my home, I am using eclipse, and code blocks. But for the sake of use in academic exams. thats why.

Comment: What about Boraland Turbo c++ 4.5

Comment: `#include <vector.h> // :)`

Comment: I *owned* that version of Turbo C 2.0. It was the first commercial software product I ever purchased (I kinda figured it had all the other products in it if you stretched your mind enough =P). Man that was *forever* ago.

Comment: The best thing is to try get a refund and join a new college where they don't prescribe a 20 year old compiler.

Comment: A friend of mine runs a company that does embedded C development for various microprocessors.  That is, stuff that you CAN'T build with Visual Studio, Eclipse,gcc, etc... One of his interview screening techniques is to send applicants a zip file of a Turbo C install in addition to a coding problem to do on it. His reasoning is that he's had to let go of some poor developers that struggled with low-end tools. So if they can't install Turbo C, they aren't a good fit.

Comment: So before you pass judgment on this student's school... consider the possibility that he may be taking a EE class in microprocessors, embedded design, or something only tangential to CS.

Comment: It's shameful that schools still often insist on using tools like Turbo C. They can't argue that's it's due to the cost of the tools since there are more than one modern, free C++ toolchains including free IDEs for them. And there have been for many years.  It's purely being too lazy to update the curriculum. Do these schools still teach international studies using Cold War era maps or electronics using vacuum tubes?

Comment: I started to program with power-C in 1986. IMO not much has been changed since: the learned concepts are still valid. Understanding that makes the difference in between academic and occupational education. I just hope, that the reason is not that the lecture is originally prepared at 1980 and it's being just parroted by any unfortunate junior assistant teacher available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no "latest version" of these products -- Turbo C was discontinued in 1990, and Turbo C++ in 1993. Both are over 20 years old (they may very well be older than you are!), and will only build 16-bit DOS executables which won't even ***run*** on most modern computers. They cannot be used to interact with any sort of modern programming APIs -- in particular, they cannot interact with the network, nor can they create a standard Windows user interface. Basically, you're stuck in the past.

I won't go quite as far as to say that you should find a better school. But you should keep in mind that what you are learning will be almost entirely irrelevant to your employment -- a lot has changed in the last 20 years, especially for C++. (The C++ STL wasn't even fully standardized in 1993, so there will be some significant differences even there.)

Comment: You can run Turbo C++ in DosBox just fine. And if you're a hardcore programmer, you can even replace the standard library with your own and make .COM and .EXE programs built with the compiler run on bare metal, off the bootloader, using BIOS functions and directly manipulating with the hardware. I've done just that. So, I wouldn't be so sure about the executables being unable to run on most modern computers.

Comment: DosBox's entire purpose is to pretend to be an old computer, so yes. But that hardly counts as running on a modern computer. :)

Comment: Interesting logic, oh well.